# will the timer started by "setitimer()" be restarted?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Each [`task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1193) in linux kernel has a field named "real timer", which is a [`struct hrtimer`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/source/include/linux/hrtimer.h#L108) (high resolution timer). When we set a timer using [`setitimer`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer), it sets the "real timer" in the process to be expired by the given value. When it is expired, the function named [`it_real_fn`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/source/include/linux/timer.h#L290) is called. Here is the [source code in Linux kernel 2.6.39.4](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/time/itimer.c#L136):

```c
/*
 * The timer is automagically restarted, when interval != 0
 */
enum hrtimer_restart it_real_fn(struct hrtimer *timer)
{
    struct signal_struct *sig =
        container_of(timer, struct signal_struct, real_timer);

    trace_itimer_expire(ITIMER_REAL, sig->leader_pid, 0);
    kill_pid_info(SIGALRM, SEND_SIG_PRIV, sig->leader_pid);

    return HRTIMER_NORESTART;
}
```

I found that it returns [`HRTIMER_NORESTART`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/hrtimer.h#L57), which means it shall not be restarted. However, if we assign an interval value when calling `setitimer`, meaning that we want to trigger the timer at every interval, where shall the "real timer" be restarted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in saying that the `it_real_fn` function will not restart the real-time timer but it is not the function that is called on timer expiration when using `setitimer`.

The `setitimer` function is part of the POSIX timers and their Linux implementation is in [`posix-timers.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/source/kernel/posix-timers.c), In this file, the function [`posix_timer_fn`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/source/kernel/posix-timers.c#L375), which may return both `HRTIMER_RESTART` and `HRTIMER_NORESTART` is defined and assigned to the `it_real_fn` of the `struct hrtimer` (the code which sets this function as the timer callback is in [`common_timer_set`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/source/kernel/posix-timers.c#L795), which is called by the POSIX timer initialization).

Comment: But in the function "do_setitimer()", it uses the hrtimer in "task struct". And that timer's callback function is set to be "it_real_fn" in "fork.c". And in linux 2.6.39.4, the "do_setitimer()" is defined in "itimer.c".

Comment: The timer callback being set to `it_real_fn` is the expected behavior, since timers are not inherited across a `fork` call. What do you mean by *And in linux 2.6.39.4, the "do_setitimer()" is defined in "itimer.c"*? This function is still defined there in 5.0.3.